# How to Send C++ Struct Message from C# Socket?

Tags: c#

This is the C++ Message that i need to pass from C#:

```
struct   LoginMessage:public NMessage
{

 char   szUser[ 16 ];
 char   szPass[ 16 ];

    LoginMessage()
    {
       msgId   = CTRL_SESSION_LOGIN;
       msgSize = sizeof( LoginMessage );
    }

};

struct NMessage
{
    DWORD           msgSize;
    union
    {
        DWORD       msgId;
        struct
        {
            BYTE    msgId0;
            BYTE    msgId1;
            BYTE    msgId2;
            BYTE    msgId3;
        };
    };

    NMessage() 
    {
    }

    BOOL IsLegal()
    {
        return msgSize>=sizeof(NMessage) && msgSize
```

What is the equivalent of this in C# so that C++ can understand this message?
Sample code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question..

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LoginMessage
        {
            public int msgSize;
            public int msgId;

            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
            public string szUser;

            [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 16)]
            public string szPass;
        }
```

It is important to take note of the sequence of the class properties so that the byte array you send to c++ is exactly the same as what it expects.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/marshalCPPclass.aspx). it's a nice marshaling guid.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [StructLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.aspx) attribute on MSDN.  There is a good example on that page on how to create a struct that can be marshalled correctly.  You can also look at http://www.pinvoke.net to see different examples of how the Windows API structs are defined to be marshaled.  Once you have the struct defined right, you should be able to use [Marshal.StructureToPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx) or [Marshal.PtrToStructure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4ca6d5z7.aspx).  Here's a short article on it: http://geekswithblogs.net/taylorrich/archive/2006/08/21/88665.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I usually manually serialize data using something like this.

```
class NMessage {

    byte[] buffer;

    //ctor to create a new message for sending.
    public NMessage(int nSize) {
         buffer = new byte[nSize];
         Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(nSize), 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(UInt32));
    }

    //ctor to create msg from received data.
    publix NMessage(byte[] buffer) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
    }

    public UInt32 MessageId {
        get { return BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 4);
        set { Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(value), 0, buffer, 4, sizeof(UInt32)); }
    }

    ...        

    public Byte MessageId2 {
        get { return buffer[6]; }
        set { buffer[6] = value; }
    }

    ...

    public UInt32 Size {
        get { return BitConverter.ToUInt32(buffer, 0) }
    }

    public Byte[] Buffer {
        get { return buffer; }
    }
}
```

---

```
class LoginMessage : NMessage {

    Encoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding(); //or whatever encoding you need.

    public LoginMessage() : base(16 + 16) {
        this.MessageId = CTRL_SESSION_LOGIN;
    }

    public LoginMessage(NMessage message) : base(message.Buffer) {
    }

    public string User {
        get { return encoding.GetString(buffer, 8, 16); }
        set { Buffer.BlockCopy(encoding.GetBytes(value), 0, buffer, 8, 16);
    }

    public string Pass {
        get { return encoding.GetString(buffer, 24, 16); }
        set { Buffer.BlockCopy(encoding.GetBytes(value), 0, buffer, 24, 16);
    } 
 }
```

So you simply create you new message, set it's data, then send the Buffer property.

```
Send((new LoginMessage {
              User = "user",
              Pass = "pass",
          }).Buffer);
```

On the receiving end, if you have enough data, you can build the message from the byte[] you receive.

```
byte[] recvBuf = new byte[MAX_RECV];
int recvSize = Receive(recvBuf);
...
var message = new NMessage(recvBuf);
if (message.MessageId == CTRL_SESSION_LOGIN)
    var login = new LoginMessage(message);
    var user = login.User;
    ...
```

That's just a rough overview anyway, the code obviously needs a cleanup as I reduced it to only demonstrate the idea.